# VBA vlookup not producing right material

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I am using vlookup in VBA to pull matching data that I have consolidated. Because of numbers, I didn't consolidate all the data and am now trying to pull some data from the original data by using vlookup.

I am not sure where my vlookup code is wrong, because for multiple rows it'll produce the same output even though the criteria is different.

This is my code:

```
Dim i As Integer 
N = 10000
Range("H2").Activate
myrange = Range(ActiveCell, Cells(ActiveCell.End(xlDown).Row, 
 ActiveCell.End(xlToRight).Column))
 Range("C2").Select
 For i = 2 To N
    userlogin = Range("C" & i)
    UserName = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(userlogin, myrange, 1)
    UserID = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(userlogin, myrange, 2)
    Range("A" & i) = UserName
    Range("B" & i) = UserID
   Next i
```

So basically, my data looks like the attached image but for a lot more rows. Column C is what I'm using as my criteria to match. In the end, I want columns H and I to be columns A and B. Right now, however, when I do it I get the same value for all

[mydataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VkzJE.png)

Comment: It's good practice to supply the last argument to vlookup as FALSE, so you only get exact matches.  FYI there's nothing in your attached image.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know about the image. I'll try to get a new one attached as an example. I added the false and it's still not working. I get "Run-Time Error '1004'": Unable to get the VLookup property of the WorksheetFunction class" 
I've tried resolving this, but still can't figure out why it's giving me that error

Comment: That means it’s not finding any match

Comment: 2 issues: (i) `myrange` is a `Range` variable, so you should be assigning its value with the `Set` statement. (ii) to use `VLOOKUP()` the value being sought must be in the FIRST column of the lookup range - this isn't so in your case, where the _User Login_ is the THIRD column of the lookup range.